# Best approach for creating a generic REST response for a database model

Tags: java, android, rest, design-patterns

I'm creating a REST api specifically for serving my android application requests. Some of the operations exposed by the API just queries the database and returns data to be displayed by the app.
However, I would like these operations to return a generic REST response, so that the data queried from the database are displayed on the UI without the need to create a response attribute for each field.

For example, i have an api operation which returns a list of transactions from the database which are displayed inside a list view.The attributes shown inside each list view item depends on the type of the transaction.
So i thought of two approaches for constructing my ***ResponseTransaction*** class:

1- Just create an attribute for each database field which needs to be displayed: ***id, description, amount, time, date, type*** ... and based on the type , android would detect which attributes to display inside each item.

2- Second approach is to tell android what to display through returning a generic response holding: ***HashMap(Label, Value)*** where values represents necessary database fields.

By using the first approach, I should update apk each time i add a new transaction type.However this is not the case in the second approach which just requires a new service deployment.

So do you think that the second approach is the best way to go for creating generic REST responses for the database operations and is it a good practice to couple REST responses to the client if we are sure that the service is only used internally by our android or web application.

Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you still wouldn't need to update the apk if you want to have different events happen for new transaction types

Comment: I'm assuming that i have a stable design for the transaction item, so i want to be able to integrate any new transaction type which holds extra data to the same apk as long as the new type doesn't require special design. So this would save me from publishing new apk for each new transaction type which only holds new data without design effects.

Comment: Anyone would like to add an advice ?